# json_decode() returns NULL

Tags: php, json, curl

I call web services to fetch some data.The code is below

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=windows-1253');
//$jsonobj = '{"Peter":35,"Ben":37,"Joe":43}';
//$jsonData ='{service:login,username:demo,password:demo,appid:256}';

$jsonData = array(
 'service' => 'login',    
 'username' => 'demo',
 'password' => 'demo',
 'appid' =>  '256'
);

//API Url
$url = 'http://myservice/s2services';

//Encode the array into JSON.
$postdata = json_encode($jsonData);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$result_array = json_decode($output, true);

var_dump($output);
```

The problem is when i try to decode json object.When i try this with this line of code `$result_array = json_decode($output, true);` returns NULL

Output from curl_exec  below

```
string(514) "{"success": true, "clientID":"9J8pHsHKOKzgR59M9JL2RLLKULb3I6WbDKCbDZ1KLNbLGN94OqbOJLHLH4XsHIKtGcnLLYKtGYKtH7LLSNb5LYKtGoKrGt9EKoKrH5KbDKDGGKHKSb55", "objs":[{"COMPANY" : "1000","COMPANYNAME" : "Company Demo ΑΕ","BRANCH" : "1000","BRANCHNAME" : "Athens","MODULE" : "13","MODULENAME" : "Customer","REFID" : "47","REFIDNAME" : "Design ","USERID" : "1","FINALDATE" : "","ROLES" : "","XSECURITY" : "0","EXPTIME" : ""}], "ver":"5.00.520.11321", "sn":"01100313514211", "off":false, "pin":false, "appid":"256"}"
```

Where is the problem here with my code ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to find out what's wrong

Comment: json_last_error_msg() returns this  Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: @Phil sorry, i was thinking he was echoing it

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Your `var_dump()` says the string is 514 characters long but the example in your question is only 504.

Comment: $output = mb_convert_encoding($output, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-7'); solved the problem.Thanks for any help Phil, Berto99